# Prevent changing status bar when opening page with popover

Tags: swift, popover

I open a page programmatically with popover, the theme of the app is light so the status bar labels are black. 
But when the popover gets open, the the labels are status bar also gets white and nothing can be seen in the status bar.

here is the screenshot
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDiO8.png)

here is the code to open popover

```
 func showlistCard() {
     let vc = ContainerlistCard()
     vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
     present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Then I searched, and I found out that I can change the style of status bar with these code

```
 public override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
       return .default
  }
```

and in the `viewWillAppear`

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
 }
```

I added it in both page, the page that open the popover and the page that gets opened, both of them are not working for me. 
Any suggestion? many thanks

Comment: Can you add screenshot of result you got?

Comment: Thanks, I added in the first post

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the status bar for the entire app all you need to do is:

1. In Info.plist set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`
2. Left side of XCode slect project > Targets > Select your project > Under General > Deployment Info > Select Status Bar Style: Light

Comment: The status bar in the entire app is fine, I just have problem in this popover page

Comment: As the answer states, if you need to keep it constant then use this. It would automatically fix your issue.

Comment: This configuration is already set and I still have this problem

Comment: Did you check step 1 in the answer?

Comment: yes, when it's NO, the status bar is hidden (cant be seen) in the whole app, and when it's YES, I have the same problem in the popover page